# Change image resource when clicking on ImageView inside the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change my device's image resource inside the recyclerview at the specific position whenever i click at it (click at the image, not the item). I tried to put setOnClickListener() inside the onBindViewHolder() method but only the last item affected. [here is my recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTBoH.png)

here is my Adapter:

```
public class Device_RV_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Device_View_Holder> {

List<Device_Data> list= Collections.emptyList();
Context context;

public Device_RV_Adapter(List<Device_Data> list,Context context){
    this.list=list;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public Device_View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.device_row_layout,parent,false);
    Device_View_Holder holder = new Device_View_Holder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Device_View_Holder holder, final int position) {

    holder.device_id.setText(list.get(position).device_id);
    holder.home.setText(list.get(position).home_id);
    holder.room.setText(list.get(position).room);
    holder.current.setText(list.get(position).current);
    holder.switch_key.setImageResource(list.get(position).switch_key);
    holder.device.setTag(position);
    holder.device.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (int)v.getTag();
            if(list.get(pos).flag==true){
                list.get(pos).flag = false;
            }
            else if(list.get(pos).flag==false){
                list.get(pos).flag = true;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });

    if(list.get(position).flag == true)
        holder.device.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan_off);
    else if(list.get(position).flag==false)
        holder.device.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan_on);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView){
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
public void insert(int position,Device_Data device_data){
    list.add(position,device_data);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
public void remove(Device_Data device_data){
    int position = list.indexOf(device_data);
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

My ViewHolder:

```
public class Device_View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

CardView cv;
TextView device_id,home,room,current;
public static ImageView device, switch_key;
boolean flag;
public Device_View_Holder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cv=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_cv);
    device_id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_id);
    home=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_id);
    room=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.room);
    current=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.current);
    device=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_img);
    switch_key=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_key);
}
```

And my Data class:

```
public class Device_Data {
public String device_id,home_id,room,current;
public int device,switch_key;
boolean flag;
public Device_Data(String device_id, String home_id, String room, String current,int device,int switch_key,boolean flag){
    this.device_id=device_id;
    this.home_id=home_id;
    this.room=room;
    this.current=current;
    this.device=device;
    this.switch_key=switch_key;
    this.flag=flag;
}
```

When I click to the device's image, if it's on (flag=true), changed to "fan_off". If it's off, change to "fan_on". Just like a switch. Can anyone help me with this situation? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need of that for loop inside `onBindViewHolder()`, as this method is called for all the items in the list and you don't have to explicitly run loop for all the items again.

Replace this piece of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        if(position==i){
                holder.device.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(list.get(position).flag==true)
                            holder.device.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan_off);
                        else if(list.get(position).flag==false){
                            holder.device.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan_on);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

with this:

```
// here setTag is used to attach the position with each view being inflated.

holder.device.setTag(position);
holder.device.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        int pos = (int)v.getTag();
        if(list.get(pos).flag==true){
           list.get(pos).flag = false;
          }
        else{
           list.get(pos).flag = true;
          }
     notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

   });

 if(list.get(position).flag == true)
    holder.device.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan_off);
 else
    holder.device.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan_on);
```

we check here if the flag is true or false and when user clicks on button, change the values accordingly so that when notifyDataSetChanged() is called it populates the views with newly changed values of flags and hence make the relevant views selected or unselected.

Comment: Thanks for your help but there's same error again. Only last item effected. There's an error that you put notifyDataSetChanged() outside the onClick() method so i put it in the if() and else if() but nothing change :(

Comment: @Hungcao  send me the structure of your list here ravinder.bhandari08@gmail.com

Comment: also remove this line for onBindViewHolder()  holder.device.setImageResource(list.get(position).device);

Comment: list structure is the Device_Data class that i uploaded above :)

Comment: I removed it but still nothing change

Comment: this code should work, I've tested it properly, or explain little bit more what do you exactly mean by only last item effected.

Comment: It means it's only affect on the last row of the recyclerview, the others nothing change when i clicked

Comment: I try to log every time i click, everything is correct but i don't understand why only the last row worked

Comment: can you update your adapter code here on stackoverflow with the changes i just told you :)

Comment: gone through it several times, nothing wrong here, what is the default value you use for flag when you create device_data object and please update onclick() code for little optimization, see my answer.

Comment: i used socket.io to get data from the server, the data is the information of the device, it's a JSONObject and i get the device's status from that. if device status = 0, set flag = true. If device status=1, set flag=false.

Comment: Oh, It's worked ! That's my false that I set the List static and when i set back in normal, it's worked. Sorry for wasting your time :(