# How to update imageview from the parent recyclerview after click on nested recyclerview's imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Please check following screenshot, I want to update imageview from parent recyclerview when user click on imageview from nested recyclerview.
I have taken two individual adapters for for parent & nested recyclerview.I am not able to do the functionality for updating image, kindly help.

[image]

Parent Recyclerview Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

private ArrayList<PLDModel> dataList;
private Context mContext;
public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PLDModel> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_view, null);
    ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

    final String itemTitle = dataList.get(i).getTitle();
    final String itemDescription = dataList.get(i).getDescription();

    ArrayList<SmallImages> singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getSmallImages();

    itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + itemTitle + " </b> " + itemDescription));

    SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

    itemRowHolder.recyclerSmallImageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    itemRowHolder.recyclerSmallImageList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    itemRowHolder.recyclerSmallImageList.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
}

public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemTitle,  expandImage;
    protected ImageView bookmarkImage,largeImage;
    protected RecyclerView recyclerSmallImageList;

    protected Button btnMore;


    public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.bookmarkImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
        this.largeImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.large_image);
        this.expandImage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        this.recyclerSmallImageList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_small_image_list);

    }

}
```

}

Nested Recyclerview Adapter:

```
public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

private ArrayList<SmallImages> itemsList;
private Context mContext;

public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SmallImages> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.small_images_view, null);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    SmallImages singleItem = itemsList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView itemImage;

    public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        //this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_small_image);


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }

}
```

}

Comment: try this link ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108222/change-image-resource-when-clicking-on-imageview-inside-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Using two Recyclerview will be hard to control rather than use a Single adapter and control everything from there.I have just worked on this type of thing that's why I am posting my code there may be some unwanted code which u may need.

/////Adapter class

```
public class AdapterTodayTrip extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTodayTrip.VHItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int rowLayout;
    private List<ModelRouteDetailsUp> dataMembers;
    private ArrayList<ModelRouteDetailsUp> arraylist;
    private ArrayList<ModelKidDetailsUp> arraylist_kids;
    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomNumberFromArray;

    private ModelRouteDetailsUp personaldata;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    String img_baseurl = "";
    String item = "";

    public AdapterTodayTrip(Context mcontext, int rowLayout, List<ModelRouteDetailsUp> tripList, String flag, String img_baseurl) {
        this.mContext = mcontext;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.dataMembers = tripList;
        wordList.clear();
        this.img_baseurl = img_baseurl;
        arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        arraylist_kids = new ArrayList<>();
        arraylist.addAll(dataMembers);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(mcontext);
        pDialog = KPUtils.initializeProgressDialog(mcontext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterTodayTrip.VHItem onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new AdapterTodayTrip.VHItem(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataMembers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterTodayTrip.VHItem viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        try {
            personaldata = dataMembers.get(position);
            if (!KPHashmapUtils.m_ride_route_details_up.get(position).getKidpool_route_id().isEmpty() && !KPHashmapUtils.m_ride_route_details_up.get(position).getKidpool_route_id().equals("null")) {
                viewHolder.tv_trip_id.setText("#" + KPHashmapUtils.m_ride_route_details_up.get(position).getKidpool_route_id());
            }

            ****///////inflate the child list here and onclick on the image below in the inflated view it will load the image in the main view****
            if (personaldata.getKidlist().size() > 0) {
                viewHolder.linear_childview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.tv_total_count.setText(""+personaldata.getKidlist().size());
                viewHolder.id_gallery.removeAllViews();
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 8, 0);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                for (int i = 0; i < personaldata.getKidlist().size(); i++) {
                    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_child_list, null);
                    view.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
                    RelativeLayout rl_txt = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl_txt);
                    RelativeLayout rl_img = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl_img);

                    TextView tv_count = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
                    com.app.kidpooldriver.helper.CircularTextView tv_name = (com.app.kidpooldriver.helper.CircularTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                    final CircleImageView iv_circular = (CircleImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_circular);
                    int count = i + 1;
                    String count1 = "0";
                    if (count <= 10) {
                        count1 = "0" + count;
                    }

                    tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(count1));
                    viewHolder.id_gallery.addView(view);
                    final String baseurl = img_baseurl + "" + personaldata.getKidlist().get(i).getKid_image();
**/////set the url of the small image in the tag here**
                    if(!baseurl.isEmpty()) {
                        iv_circular.setTag(baseurl);
                    }
                    if (!personaldata.getKidlist().get(i).getKid_image().isEmpty()) {
                        GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) rl_img.getBackground();
                        bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#A6b1a7a6"));
                        rl_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //rl_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("aimg_baseurl", baseurl);
                        try {
                            Picasso.with(mContext)
                                    .load(baseurl)
                                    .resize(60,60)
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .into(iv_circular);

                            iv_circular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String url=iv_circular.getTag().toString().trim();
                                    if(!url.isEmpty())
                                    KPUtils.showToastShort(mContext,url);
                                    Picasso.with(mContext)
                                            .load(url)
                                            .resize(60,60)
                                            .centerCrop()
                                            .into(viewHolder.img_child);
                                }
                            });

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }else{
                viewHolder.linear_childview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv_members;
        ImageView img_child;
        TextView tv_trip_id, tv_trip_status, tv_vehicle_number, tv_trip_start_time, tv_trip_end_time, tv_trip_way, tv_total_count;
        LinearLayout id_gallery,linear_childview;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_child= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_child);
            cv_members = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_members);
            tv_trip_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trip_id);
            tv_trip_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trip_status);
            tv_vehicle_number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_vehicle_number);
            tv_trip_start_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trip_start_time);
            tv_trip_end_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trip_end_time);
            tv_trip_way = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trip_way);
            tv_total_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_total_count);
            id_gallery = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_gallery);
            linear_childview= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_childview);
        }
    }
}
```

**/////////////////////////// this layout is inflated in every row
view_child_list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_circular"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:civ_border_color="#d27959"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_txt"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/gy_ring_circular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.app.kidpooldriver.helper.CircularTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            fontPath="fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="01"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/gy_ring_circular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_count"
            fontPath="fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="01"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

///// this is the mianlayout which is inflated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cv_members"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fifteen"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="#KD09201701"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twenty"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/light_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="In Progress"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Route 26U-26D"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="@color/route_textcolor" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_start_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="06:30am"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_textcolor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_end_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="08:30am"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_textcolor"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_trip_way"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Chingrighata > NiccoPark > SDF > College More > DLF 1 > Eco Space"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_textcolor"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_child"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_childview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fifteen"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/id_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ly_ring_circular"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_total_count"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
                    fontPath="fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"
                    android:text="+20"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**/////POJO CLASS &json parsing & Adapter /////**

```
public class ModelRouteDetailsUp {

    String city_id;
    String area_name;
    String area_status;
    String is_active;
    String areas;

    private ArrayList<ModelKidDetailsUp> kidlist;

    ///////this is the kid list 
    public ArrayList<ModelKidDetailsUp> getKidlist() {
        return kidlist;
    }

    public void setKidlist(ArrayList<ModelKidDetailsUp> kidlist) {
        this.kidlist = kidlist;
    }
 }

**///json parsing.......**
 public boolean addRideDetails(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Boolean flag = false;
        String isstatus = "";

        if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.length() > 0) {
            try {
                JSONArray mainArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("schedules");

                for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length(); i++) {
                    ModelRouteDetailsUp modelRouteDetails = new ModelRouteDetailsUp();
                    JSONObject c = mainArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    //////   For Route Details   //////
                    JSONObject route_details = c.getJSONObject("route_details");
                    modelRouteDetails.setDs_id(route_details.optString("ds_id"));
                    modelRouteDetails.setDriver_id(route_details.optString("driver_id"));
                    modelRouteDetails.setTrip_id(route_details.optString("trip_id"));
                    modelRouteDetails.setRoute_id(route_details.optString("route_id"));
                    modelRouteDetails.setVehicle_id(route_details.optString("vehicle_id"));
                    modelRouteDetails.setStart_time(route_details.optString("start_time"));
                    modelRouteDetails.setEnd_time(route_details.optString("end_time"));

                    //////   For Allotted Kids  //////
                    JSONArray kidArray = c.getJSONArray("alloted_kids");
                    ArrayList<ModelKidDetailsUp> genre = new ArrayList<ModelKidDetailsUp>();
                    if (kidArray.length() > 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < kidArray.length(); j++) {
                            ModelKidDetailsUp kidDetailsUp = new ModelKidDetailsUp();
                            JSONObject kidObject = kidArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            kidDetailsUp.setKid_name(kidObject.getString("kid_name"));
                            kidDetailsUp.setKid_gender(kidObject.getString("kid_gender"));
                            kidDetailsUp.setKid_dob(kidObject.getString("kid_dob"));
                            kidDetailsUp.setKid_image(kidObject.getString("kid_image"));
                            genre.add(kidDetailsUp);
                        }
                    }
///////add the kidlist here
                    modelRouteDetails.setKidlist(genre);

////main array contains all the data i.e route details and kidlist for every row
KPHashmapUtils.m_ride_route_details_up.add(modelRouteDetails);
                    //}
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return flag;
    }



**/////adapter callfrom class**

private void showData() {
        if (KPHashmapUtils.m_ride_route_details_up.size() > 0){
            adapterTodayTrip = new AdapterTodayTrip(mContext, R.layout.list_item_todaytrip, KPHashmapUtils.m_ride_route_details_up, "TodayTrip",img_baseurl);
            rv_trip_list.setAdapter(adapterTodayTrip);
        }else {
            tv_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nayank I have posted a full working code and my requirement is same as yours.Ping if u need help

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the solution is to pass custom interface listener into the nested adapter and than the nested adapter will report any time one of his item clicked.

1.
You can create interface like:

```
public interface INestedClicked {
   onNestedItemClicked(Drawable drawble)
}
```

2.
Pass in the constructor of `SectionListDataAdapter` a `INestedClicked`:

```
SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = newSectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems, new INestedClicked() {
    @Override
    void onNestedItemClicked(Drawable drawble) {
       // Do whatever you need after the click, you get the drawable here
    }
});
```

3. In the constructor of `SectionListDataAdapter` save the instance of the listener as adapter parameter

   `private INestedClicked listener;`

4.
When nested item clicked report the listener:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(listener != null){
        listener.onNestedItemClicked(imageView.getDrawable());
    }
}
```